# Preventing running total from going negative in Oracle

Tags: oracle, function, sum, cumulative-sum, analytical

Column 'amount' has value 5 in first row, and value -10 in second row.

Is there a way to make oracle's sum(amount) over() function to return 0 instead of -5 for the second row?

Comment: use a case statement.  `case when windowfunction <0 then 0 else windowfunction end as Amount`  or make that a CTE and select from the cte and ahve the case statement evaluate the amount..

Comment: But i want the 0 to be reflected in the following rows (3rd, 4th and so on). Case statement wonn't help me with that.

Comment: @Marko - This is why it is helpful to post some sample data which explains your examples

Comment: as a CTE that evaluates each row after the window function executes...yes, yes it would.

Comment: You asked, "Is there a way to make oracle's sum(amount) over() function to return 0 instead of -5 for the second row?" No.  One is unable to interrupt the window function and "Reset" the value, perhaps using a separate field to keep a running total independant of the window function may work. I found but a different approach using a recursive CTE offers greater flexibility to make this possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blatantly using Rajesh Chamarthi's example source: but altering to show more negative and positive... and showing how a case would change all the negative to zero while maintaining the other amounts...

```
with t as (
  select 5 as x, 1 as id from dual
  union all
  select -10, 2 as id from dual
  union all
  select 7, 3 as id from dual
  union all
  select -5, 4 as id from dual
  union all
  select -2, 5 as id from dual
),  
B as (select  t.x, 
        case when sum(x) over (order by id) < 0 then 0 
              else sum(x) over (order by id) 
        end Amount
 from t
 order by id)
 Select X, Case when amount < 0 then 0 else amount end as Amount from B;

  T   Amount
  5      5
-10      0
  7      2
 -5      0
 -2      0
```

----Attempt 2 (1st attempt preserved as comments below reference it)

I couldn't figure out how to interrupt the window function to reset the value to 0 when amount fell below 0... so I used a recursive CTE which gave me greater control.

If id's are not sequential, we could add a row_Number so we have an ID to join on... or we could use min() where > oldID.   I assumed we have a single key unique ID or some way of "Sorting" the records in the order you want the sum to occur...

```
with aRaw as (
  select 5 as x, 15 as id from dual
  union all
  select -10, 20 as id from dual
  union all
  select 7, 32 as id from dual
  union all
  select 2, 46 as id from dual
  union all
  select -15, 55 as id from dual
  union all
  select 3, 68 as id from dual
),
t as (Select A.*, Row_number() over (order by ID) rn from aRAW A),

CTE(RN, ID, x, SumX) AS (
Select T.RN, T.ID, x, X from t WHERE ID = (Select min(ID) from t)
UNION ALL
Select T.RN, T.ID, T.X, case when T.X+CTE.SumX < 0 then 0 else T.X+Cte.sumX end from T
INNER JOIN CTE
 on  CTE.RN+1=T.RN)

Select * from cte;
```

.

1. CTE: ARaw is just a sample data set
2. CTE: T adds a sequental row number incase there are gaps in the IDs allowing for a more simple joining approach on the recursive CTE.
3. CTE: CTE is the recursive CTE that keeps a running total and has a case statement to reset the running total to 0 when it falls below 0

Comment: So you want to restart numbering when 0 is reached; got it.

Comment: @Marko - you can just ignore the negative numbers in the case statement and then do sum on top..

Comment: Rajesh, that would give me 5 instead of 0 in the 2nd row (looking at the result table in xQbert's post)

Comment: @marko No I know of no way to interrupt the Window function to reset the sum to zero when it falls negative. However, using a recursive CTE to do the Summing, we have greater control and it becomes possible. (Sorry had to do real job for a few hours! :P)

Comment: @xQbert, it works like a charm! I didn't know recursive CTE existed and I don't think it's possible to do it with the window function.Thank you!

Comment: Common table expressions are powerful mojo and recursive ones can be risky, it is reecursion! But emensly useful

Answer (score 1):

You could use a case statement, but that would not be a true running total

```
with t as (
  select 5 as x, 1 as id from dual
  union all
  select -10, 2 as id from dual
  union all
  select 20, 3 as id from dual
  union all
  select 30, 4 as id from dual
  union all
  select 10, 5 as id from dual
)  
select  t.x, 
        case when sum(x) over (order by id) < 0 then 0 
              else sum(x) over (order by id) 
        end running_total
 from t
 order by id;

X   RUNNING_TOTAL

5   5
-10 0
20  15
30  45
10  55
```